# Adjective rule for quelque chose, quelqu'un, rien

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs

"It's something beautiful."

> C'est quelque chose de beau. (**not**: C'est quelque belle chose.)

"He's someone special."

> C'est quelqu'un de spécial. (**not**: C'est quelqu'un spécial.)

"It's nothing very important."

> Ce n'est rien de très important. (**not**: C'est n'est rien très important.)

Is there a name for this rule where we need to add *de* and use the masculine form of the adjective for *quelque chose*, *quelqu'un*, and *rien*? Also are there other pronouns besides these three to which the rule applies?

Comment: An easy way to remember is that there is no article. A normal construction is "*une personne spéciale*" but here you don't have the "*un/une*". "*Quelqu'un*", "*quelque chose*" and "*rien*" replace "*un/une [something]*" so normal construction rules can't apply.

Comment: Interesting question! For *quelque chose*, there is a difference between two types of modifiers: *un petit/vrai/authentique quelque chose de beau/grand/spécial*...

Comment: @GAMPUB Do you mean that one can say "un petit/vrai/authetique quelque chose"?

Comment: Yes, you will find examples on Google with de extensions too.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat What about, for example, "beaucoup de choses". Do we say "beaucoup de choses spéciales" or "beaucoup de choses de spécial"?

Comment: @user11550 Interesting question. I'd say "*beaucoup de choses*", "*plein de choses*" "*trop de choses*" express **quantity**, they acts like "*des choses*". "*Quelque chose*" is a whole your cannot separate, it doesn't behave like "*[something] chose*", it's a special entity. And "*Quelque chose*", "*quelqu'un*" and "*rien*" express **existence** (more or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "*Quelque chose*" (ou "*quelqu'un*) est un **pronom indéfini**, exprimant ici la quantité (comme aucun, certain, rien, beaucoup, etc...), la nature de la chose dont on juge la quantité, est introduite par "de".

> Are there other pronouns besides these three to which the rule applies

Aux autres pronoms indéfinis expression d'une quantité.

- La règle qui s'applique est la suivante:

> Quand l’adjectif qui suit quelque chose n’est pas précédé d’un pronom
>   relatif, il doit l’être de la préposition de.
>
> *Quelque chose **de** fâcheux*.
>   *Quelque chose **de** plaisant*.
>   *Quelque chose **de** merveilleux*.

Source ici: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque_chose

C'est la même chose avec "quelqu'un".

*Hier, j'ai rencontré **quelqu'un de** bien*.
Même construction que lorsque ce n'est pas un adjectif, mais une provenance:
*Je voudrais connaître **quelqu'un de** Biarritz.*

Donc, d'après cette règle, exemple de cas où on ne doit pas mettre "de" parce qu'il y a le pronom relatif qui/que:

*Quelque chose **qui me plaît**.*

*Quelqu'un **qui me va**.*

---

> C'est quelque belle chose

n'a rien à voir avec ce qui précède.
Dans ce cas "quelque", adjectif indéfini, est l'équivalent grammatical de "une":

> C'est une belle chose

Les deux phrases n'ont pas strictement le même sens, mais sont grammaticalement équivalentes. Son usage est très littéraire. Son sens: Une chose parmi d'autres.

--

Attention: Ne pas confondre la nature grammaticale de "quelque" dans "quelque chose" et quand il est utilisé comme adjectif indéfini. Son usage est très rare et littéraire, mais tout à fait correct.

Voir:  https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque

> quelque \kɛlk\ ou \kɛl.kə\ masculin et féminin identiques (**Littéraire**)
>   (Au singulier) Un parmi d’autres. — Note : Il est alors utilisé avec
>   un dénombrable. On peut dire simplement un ou une.

On peut substituer un ou une à "quelque" pour donner une formulation plus poétique ou (beaucoup) plus littéraire. Attention, il ne faut absolument pas le confondre avec "quelques".

*Je lui ai fait quelque enfant/promesse*

Est bien un singulier, ici il ne s'agit que d'un enfant, ou d'une promesse, la phrase a une connotation négative, et n'est pas la même chose que:

*Je lui ai fait quelques enfants/quelques promesses*

Où on parle de plusieurs.

Comment: Je suis confus.. est-ce que "C'est quelque chose de beau" n'est pas correcte ?

Comment: "C'est quelque chose de beau" (1) est bien correct. "C'est quelque belle chose" ne l'est pas et à un sens plus proche de "C'est une belle chose", qui n'a pas le même sens que (1).

Comment: Dans la série des exemples il faudrait écrire "C'est quelque chose beau" au lieu de "C'est quelque belle chose" pour conserver la même logique

Comment: "C'est quelque belle chose" est totalement correct, même si son emploi est très rare. Je vais mettre un lien. "Quelque" peut être un adjectif indéfini. @Stud ça n'a rien à voir. Mon exemple est correct, et tu confonds l'usage de "quelque" en tant qu'adjectif indéfini et en tant que pronom indéfini, ce qui est très différent.

Comment: J'ignorais que c'était correct, autant pour moi et merci pour la clarification.

Comment: C'est un usage très très littéraire, comme cet usage est pratiquement oublié, la plupart des gens le jugeront incorrect. Qui utilise "quelque" au singulier de nos jours? Mais il faut savoir que ça existe. Je trouve dommage qu'on laisse mourir les formulations poétiques, bientôt on ne pourra plus lire Victor Hugo...